# Sorting using switch in php

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am working on this project and I am stuck.

I have table with 3 columns Title Body and Date

When I click on "Date" I want the data to be ordered ascending, then click again for descending.

This is the code that I am struggling with:

```
$sort = (isset($_GET['sort'])) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'date'; // I AM NOT SURE WHAT DOES THIS PART DOES 

switch ($sort) {
case '1':
    $order_by = 'date ASC';

    break;

default:
    $order_by = 'date DESC';

    break;
}
```

And I have a query that looks like this:

```
  $q = "SELECT body, date, title FROM joke ORDER BY $order_by  LIMIT $start, $display "
```

MORE INFO - the code that prints the data:

```
if ($pages > 1) {

echo '<br /><p>';
$current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

// If it's not the first page, make a Previous button:
if ($current_page != 1) {
    echo '<a href="view_jokes.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">Previous</a> ';
}

// Make all the numbered pages:
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
    if ($i != $current_page) {
        echo '<a href="view_jokes.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
    } else {
        echo $i . ' ';
    }
} // End of FOR loop.

// If it's not the last page, make a Next button:
if ($current_page != $pages) {
    echo '<a href="view_jokes.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">Next</a>';
}

echo '</p>'; // Close the paragraph.

} // End of links section.
```

I AM USING THIS FOR DISPLAYING

```
 echo '<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="75%">
 <tr>
<td align="left"><b>title</b></td>
<td align="left"><b>body</b></td>
<td align="left"><b>Date</b></td>
 </tr>
   ';    
  $bg = '#FFFF99'; 

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       $bg = ($bg=='#FFFF99' ? '#E6E6E6' : '#FFFF99');
    echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">
            <td align="left">' . $row['title'] . '</td>
    <td align="left">' . $row['body'] . '</td>
     <td align="left">' . $row['date'] . '</td>

                   </tr> '; 
}
```

How do i edit this so the when i click the date it can be sorted desc or asc

Comment: SO what is the actual problem you are having? What is not working as expected?

Comment: The field Date is not clickable

Comment: `$sort` is never going to be `1` so `$order_by` will always be `date DESC`

Comment: @putvande, it still can coming from request...

Comment: @mile I updated my answer below with a way of printing your 'Date' button, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line of code :

```
$sort = (isset($_GET['sort'])) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'date';
```

is equivalent to :

```
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];
}
else {
    $sort = 'date';
}
```

Now it depends on what GET request you're sending when "Date" is clicked. According to your switch, you shoud receive `?sort=1` so the order is set to `date ASC`, else it will fall back to `date DESC`.
Does that help ?

[edit]
Oh and you don't need to `break` your last statement :

```
switch ($sort) {
    case '1':
        $order_by = 'date ASC';
        break;
    default:
        $order_by = 'date DESC';
}
```

[edit2] If you're wondering how to print the "Date" button, try something like this :

```
echo '<a href="view_jokes.php?sort=' , ($sort == '1') ? '0' : '1' , '">Date</a>';
```

[edit3] @mile, try this, and thanks again @vp_arth for the enhancements :)

```
echo '<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="75%">
<tr>
    <td align="left"><b>title</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>body</b></td>
    <td align="left"><b>Date</b></td>
</tr>
';    
$bg = '#FFFF99'; 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $bg = ($bg=='#FFFF99' ? '#E6E6E6' : '#FFFF99');
    echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">
            <td align="left">' . $row['title'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['body'] . '</td>
            <td align="left"><a href="view_jokes.php?sort=' . (!$sort) . '">' . $row['date'] . '</a></td>

            </tr> '; 
}
```

Comment: it can be even `...'.(!$sort).'...`. works this commas as concatenation?

Comment: @paulgv i added the code that i am using to display please take a look and tell me how can i change it so when i click the date it orders the data asc and desc

Comment: @mile : check the edit ;) @vp_art : thanks ! Yeah I just found out about this type of concatenation, it does work, I think I could have used dots like that : `. ($sort == '1' ? '0' : '1') .`

Comment: @paulgv 

Thank you very very much! It finally works !

Answer (score 0):

```
$sort = (isset($_GET['sort'])) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'date';
```

This will set $sort to the $_GET['sort'] value if that exists and to 'date' if it is not set... so it defaults to 'date'.

You are switching on $sort as a string of '1', so your $order_by will always be set to 'date DESC'

Comment: So if i change it case "date" it is changing but still is not clickable.

How do i make the Date field clickable and once i click to go from DESC to ASC and vice versa?